# Почему мы сериализуем DTO, вместо сущностей?

Tags: java

Всем привет.

Все мы храним сущности в базах данных (в виде записей), а передаём их значения, скажем, через REST, уже в DTO. Это общепринятая практика, но не все задумываются, почему именно так.

Один из доводов - это то, что DTO - плоский объект, не имеющий зависимостей. Он отдаёт только то, что в него перенесли из сущности. Скажем, мы открыли транзакцию, полезли в базу и, не закрывая транзакцию, что-то там достали, поработали с этим, а потом вернули этот объект на фронт. При этом, транзакция обрывается, и какие-то данные, которые были связаны с другими с аттрибутом `lazy fetch`, переданы не были. А фронт их ждёт.

Или другой пример. Мой товарищ искал отель, нашёл подходящий, а потом, поскольку он программист, он решил посмотреть, какой объект он получает при запросах. Выяснилось, что разработчики тоже не стали особенно париться и просто передают туда сущность, а поскольку многие зависимости были связаны с аттрибутом `eager fetch`, то на фронт притянуло ещё и промокоды, перебрав которые, он получил скидку на отель 50%.

Окей.

Есть ли ещё какие-то доводы, запрещающие сериализовать сущности и передавать их напрямую на фронт?

Comment: DTO позволяет избежать зависимости между слоем данных и представлением. Формат ответа сервиса может меняться ежедневно, а структура БД не меняться годами.

Answer (score 7):

Запрета передавать сущности на фронт, как такового нет. DTO предпочтительнее потому, что:

- Устраняется зависимость между структурой данных в БД и их представлением;
- Можно пересылать по сети между бэком и фронтом только те данные, которые действительно нужны, а не всю модель целиком (экономия времени и трафика).